# python: combine each element of a list to a list of tuple

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list of numbers:

```
list_A = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have another list of tuples:

```
list_B = [(10, 11), (20,21), (30,31), (40,41), (50,51)]
```

I want to combine list_A and list_B, become like below:

```
[(10,11,1), (20,21,2), (30,31,3), (40,41,4), (50,51,5)]
```

what's the most efficient way to do such?

Comment: Please edit the code of your own attempt to solve this into your question and show what’s wrong with the output.

Comment: Iterate the list, and add elements from `list_A` to corresponding tuple in `list_B`. You can try something like `[(*list_B[i], list_A[i]) for i in range(len(list_A))]`.

Answer (score 4):

Double zip:

```
[*zip(*zip(*list_B), list_A)]
```

Comparison of the solutions so far:

```
1035 ns  1047 ns  1049 ns  [(*b, a) for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B)]
1138 ns  1140 ns  1141 ns  [(list_B[index][0], list_B[index][1], list_A[index]) for index in range(len(list_A))]
 963 ns   967 ns   993 ns  [list_B[i] + (list_A[i],) for i in range(len(list_A))]
 805 ns   820 ns   826 ns  [i + (j,) for j,i in zip(list_A,list_B)]
 947 ns   952 ns   965 ns  [*zip(*zip(*list_B), list_A)]
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJBbsMgELz7FXOpDC5SQ@xIbSUfUimvsFBkKyQlsrGFqdT28y4YSKv20D2Y8ezuDLBMH/Z11OXjZJblbMYBVg1SWahhGo2FkZNsbZb1arbHPWo0nGHLUDJUDDsREi8@QfiGgXPKQLYObVdUOlSuqHKoWtHOoR2nIssOvi@Di7whRcfQUpxHg5ahg9L4VBMJzgzBiIqcpYbANEqf5LtoNiLVJIYnZh@ZIL5ir25afZGklzp60B/iSUngHiSJCBYV/utWvusaq69M/TrLn6MUPhk@MZd2vha5m/JCx2/bkj6vrZ6Wnj6Efx/6beikcTfLNz5uvB/s7OjZzVWeSJgskQyXfuzafq7jSpx50KjDwuIrqEtKb2qTUdqSguR31Ql6Ro47EIuHZF@Ay6dwAdZvcHV3yjJIhHa6LF8)):

```
from timeit import repeat

list_A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_B = [(10, 11), (20, 21), (30, 31), (40, 41), (50, 51)]

E = [
    '[(*b, a) for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B)]',
    '[(list_B[index][0], list_B[index][1], list_A[index]) for index in range(len(list_A))]',
    '[list_B[i] + (list_A[i],) for i in range(len(list_A))]',
    '[i + (j,) for j,i in zip(list_A,list_B)]',
    '[*zip(*zip(*list_B), list_A)]',
]

for _ in range(3):
    for e in E:
        number = 100000
        times = sorted(repeat(e, globals=globals(), number=number, repeat=3))
        print(*('%4d ns ' % (t / number * 1e9) for t in times), e)
    print()
```

Comment: Benchmarks would probably be more insightful on lists of more than 5 elements!

Comment: @Stef Maybe, maybe not. Depends on whether they have longer lists or do this on many short lists. I once wrote an O(n) solution and an O(n^2) solution got accepted instead because it turned out the OP actually only had similarly small lists and the O(n^2) solution was a bit faster on those.

Comment: @Stef One might also want longer inner tuples. Or both. So that's two different dimensions. In such cases I tend to not guess, and I don't want to include four benchmarks (or even more, for small/medium/large sizes). But the benchmark code is there and should be easy to adjust if desired.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension to unpack and repack the elements, and to get the lists together for the iterations you can use `zip`.

```
list_A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list_B = [(10, 11), (20, 21), (30, 31), (40, 41), (50, 51)]

output = [(*b, a) for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B)]

>>> [(10, 11, 1), (20, 21, 2), (30, 31, 3), (40, 41, 4), (50, 51, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `zip`

```
res = [i + (j,) for j,i in zip(list_A,list_B)]
```

output:

```
[(10, 11, 1), (20, 21, 2), (30, 31, 3), (40, 41, 4), (50, 51, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

If the tuples in `list_B` are always of 2 items it would be both clearer and faster to unpack it as such:

```
[(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in zip(list_B, list_A)]
```

Borrowing @don'ttalkjustcode's benchmark code:

```
1091 ns  1109 ns  1109 ns  [(*b, a) for a, b in zip(list_A, list_B)]
1183 ns  1189 ns  1205 ns  [(list_B[index][0], list_B[index][1], list_A[index]) for index in range(len(list_A))]
1035 ns  1052 ns  1053 ns  [list_B[i] + (list_A[i],) for i in range(len(list_A))]
 843 ns   897 ns   926 ns  [i + (j,) for j,i in zip(list_A,list_B)]
 979 ns   994 ns  1015 ns  [*zip(*zip(*list_B), list_A)]
 760 ns   765 ns   767 ns  [(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in zip(list_B, list_A)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJNb4MwDL3zK3ypSJilNQWkbRKHVuqvQFEFbdqlgoBCJm378ywfpOu2w3wgL8/2sx08fpjXQeVPo57nsx56MLIX0oDsx0Eb0GIUjUmSTk7msIUKaoawQcgRCoSSB8fOOQhbIzBGEcjGoo1HuUW5R4VFhUelRSWjPEn2Li8Ba2lNshahoXAeNDQILUgFn3IkoTJCKER5ijEhMLVUJ/HO6zWPMZFhkdkuTBD32KnrRl0E6YRaatA78ajE4QFIFOG4KPyXLV3WdYm@ovw1y59RMucMn8UXO7@f170KwjGo@psNO/7Q3t3lJfaBXeThu9ucvngxRwtH78PdmXrrW6HtD2FrZzfe7cNk6cmugziRsBBEIFy6oW26qVpOYpsJGlU4cFmeKqf0pjZqqQzJSLoqTqAmSGEFxMBjLJ8BE89hQuMa9NWtsggSIZ3O8xc)

Answer (score 1):

For each element of B (a tuple), you add each element of A to the tuple. Note that this is only possible when the element of A is a tuple, hence the brackets and the comma.

Using list comprehension:

```py
list_A = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_B = [(10, 11), (20,21), (30,31), (40,41), (50,51)]

[list_B[i] + (list_A[i],) for i in range(len(list_A))]
```

Output:

```
Out[16]: [(10, 11, 1), (20, 21, 2), (30, 31, 3), (40, 41, 4), (50, 51, 5)]
```

Comment: You should avoid using `range(len(list_A))` and indexing in iterables, and instead iterate over the objects directly. It's more Pythonic and often faster too.

Answer (score 0):

```py
res = [(list_B[index][0], list_B[index][1], list_A[index]) for index in range(len(list_A))])
```

Output:

```
[(10, 11, 1), (20, 21, 2), (30, 31, 3), (40, 41, 4), (50, 51, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can do it by using for loop

List of numbers:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Tuple list of numbers:

```
list_b = [(10, 11), (20, 21), (30, 31), (40, 41), (50, 51)]
```

**As you know tuples are immutable**
So, you can create an empty list:

```
new_list = []
```

Let's run a loop to solve:

```
for i in range(len(list_a)):
        list_together = []
        list_together += list_b[i]
        list_together.append(list_a[i])
        tup = tuple(list_together)
        new_list.append(tup)
```

**Details:**

- Running the loop in the range/length of `list_a`
- `list_together` concatenates both `list_a` and `list_b`
- Append `list-a` values with `list_b` in `list_together` variable when loop runs
- `tup` converts the list into tuple and after that append into `new_list`

Finally, let's print the newly created list as output:

```
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[(10, 11, 1), (20, 21, 2), (30, 31, 3), (40, 41, 4), (50, 51, 5)]
```

Comment: Concatenation inside a for loop is slower and less pythonic than using a list comprehension.